# Why are my Ohm Robots not using Teleporters?

Tags: universe-at-war

In the game Universe At War, the first race in the campaign has teleporters to warp any of your units across the map, but my Ohm Robots do not seem to use them at all. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

To get your units to use the rapid transport towers, double right click somewhere. This will cause all your units to move as fast as possible, instead of them all going at the speed of the slowest in the group.